# Add a site on Caddy Web Server without restart

Tags: webserver, caddy

I'm setting up a static html webserver where users can upload their own files and create their own websites.
I'm using Caddy as the webserver and as far as I understand, every time a new host is added on Caddyfile there's a need to restart Caddy to start serving the new site.
I wonder if there's a way to get around that, where the other sites won't be affected or some other way without the need to restart Caddy entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got an answer from Matt Holt, the creator of Caddy:

> You could signal Caddy with USR1, which does a zero-downtime reload.

Caddy can be easily reloaded as such:

From the terminal run the following commands:

1.Get the PID from the running caddy instance:

```
ps -C caddy
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1392 pts/0    00:00:00 caddy
```

2.Send kill command with USR1 parameter

```
kill -s USR1 1392
```

And that's it. Caddy will be reloaded without affecting any other site.

Comment: what is the different between this and this: "pkill -USR1 caddy"